# A claim of Gromov in "Metric Structures for Riemannian and non-Riemannian Spaces"

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I'm trying to understand an example that occurs very early in Gromov's book "Metric Structures for Riemannian and Non-Riemannian Spaces".

On page 3, he introduces the following metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Consider points $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Write them in polar coordinates as $x_i = r_i s_i$, where $r_i \geq 0$ and $s_i \in S^{n-1}$.  We then define
$$d(x_1,x_2) = |r_1-r_2| + \text{min}(r_1,r_2) \cdot \|s_1-s_2\|^{1/2},$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the usual Euclidean distance on the sphere.  You can then define an alternate metric $d_{\ell}(x_1,x_2)$ to equal the infimum of the lengths of all continuous paths from $x_1$ to $x_2$, where the length of a path is measured using $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ in the usual way.

What he claims is that
$$d_{\ell}(x_1,x_2) = \begin{cases}
|r_1-r_2| & \text{if $s_1 = s_2$},\\
r_1+r_2   & \text{if $s_1 \neq s_2$}.
\end{cases}$$
In particular, $d_{\ell}$ induces a non-standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ where all spheres centered at the origin are discrete.

I'm having trouble proving the above formula for $d_{\ell}$.  What must be the case is that if $s_1 \neq s_2$ then paths that move the $S^{n-1}$-coordinate when the radius is nonzero must have infinite length, and this must somehow come from the $1/2$ in the exponent of $\|s_1-s_2\|$.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/2} = n^{1/2} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Think first about $\mathbb{R}$ with metric $d(x,y)=\sqrt{|x-y|}$.

Comment: Ah, I get it now, thanks!  I'll delete the question after waiting an appropriate amount of time (to make sure you see that I thanked you two!).